# my redis server breakdown sometimes for some reason I still don't figure out

Tags: node.js, redis

I am now working on the redis and node.js, they are all deployed on the aws.

However (sometimes once a day, sometimes once a week) redis would breakdown for some reason, in which all the existing and new connection to redis are all disconnected / timeout. The only way for me to fix the problem is to stop the process and restart the redis at the backend, so far I still don't figure out the problem

I wonder could it be the problem that when the app / node.js process is closed, the app don't explicitly close all the existing redis connections, is that a issue?

and can you list some other problems that could cause redis breakdown, how could I monitor the redis server on aws

Comment: Ultimately, sockets die. Without access to logging information, it is hard to say what is happening in your specific case, but losing a connection occasionally isn't hugely surprising.

Comment: haven't used `aws`, but isn't there an option to auto-restart application on failure? it should solve some problems. Also try to use an interval to call save/bigsave if you are using redis as storage.

Comment: Thank you all, all good idea and suggestions, I will try to look both of your suggestions